Correct a postgresql trigger to audit every changers happen a single row
I put my code bellow. In this code only one update for one row makes a record in MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS table. If did two changers in same row only first change makes the trigger runs and create the record but if i did the changers in two rows two records creates in the MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS table how can I fix this so every update in a single row makes an audit.
as example I change(update) BANK_ABBREVIATION first and then update status(1 to 0) and save and execute.
-- FUNCTION: public.tr_mbankactaud()

-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.tr_mbankactaud();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tr_mbankactaud()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$

DECLARE

    EVENT_TABLE_NAME  VARCHAR(100);
    EVENT_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100);
    EVENT_ACTIVITY    VARCHAR(1000);
    EVENT_DATETIME    TIMESTAMP;   
    EVENT_USER        VARCHAR(100);
    EVENT_USER_NAME   VARCHAR(100);
    EVENT_USER_CC     VARCHAR(100);
    EVENT_MACHINE     VARCHAR(100);
    EVENT_MACHINE_IP  VARCHAR(100);     
    NEW_VALUE         VARCHAR(50);
    OLD_VALUE         VARCHAR(50);  
    BANK_CODE         VARCHAR(4);
    BANK_NAME         VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN
-- INSERT DATA --

    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    
        SELECT 'MBANK' INTO EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
        SELECT 'BANK_CODE' INTO EVENT_COLUMN_NAME;
        
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_DATETIME INTO EVENT_DATETIME;               --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER INTO EVENT_USER;                       --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT USER_NAME INTO EVENT_USER_NAME FROM MUSER WHERE USER_ID = EVENT_USER;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER_CC INTO EVENT_USER_CC;                --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE INTO EVENT_MACHINE;                --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP INTO EVENT_MACHINE_IP;          --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
    
        SELECT OLD.BANK_CODE INTO OLD_VALUE;                        --FROM OLD del WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.BANK_CODE INTO NEW_VALUE;                        --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        
        SELECT NEW.BANK_CODE INTO BANK_CODE;                        --FROM OLD del WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.BANK_NAME INTO BANK_NAME; 
        
        EVENT_ACTIVITY := EVENT_USER || ' [' || EVENT_USER_NAME || ']' || ' has added a new bank code "' || NEW_VALUE || '"';
        
        IF EVENT_ACTIVITY <> '' THEN
            INSERT INTO MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP) 
            VALUES (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
        
 -- UPDATE 01 (BANK_ABBREVIATION) --
    
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND OLD.BANK_ABBREVIATION IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.BANK_ABBREVIATION THEN

        SELECT 'MBANK' INTO EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
        SELECT 'BANK_ABBREVIATION' INTO EVENT_COLUMN_NAME;
        
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_DATETIME INTO EVENT_DATETIME;                   --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER INTO EVENT_USER;                           --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT USER_NAME INTO EVENT_USER_NAME FROM MUSER WHERE USER_ID = EVENT_USER;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER_CC INTO EVENT_USER_CC;                     --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE INTO EVENT_MACHINE;                     --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP INTO EVENT_MACHINE_IP;               --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
         
        SELECT OLD.BANK_ABBREVIATION INTO OLD_VALUE;                             --FROM OLD WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.BANK_ABBREVIATION INTO NEW_VALUE;                             --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        
        SELECT NEW.BANK_CODE INTO BANK_CODE;                        --FROM OLD del WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.BANK_NAME INTO BANK_NAME;
        
        IF OLD_VALUE <> NEW_VALUE THEN
            EVENT_ACTIVITY := EVENT_USER || ' [' || EVENT_USER_NAME || '] has changed the abbreviation of the bank code ' || BANK_CODE || ' from "' || OLD_VALUE || '" to "' || NEW_VALUE || '"';
        END IF;
        
        IF EVENT_ACTIVITY <> '' THEN
            INSERT INTO MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP) 
            VALUES (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

 -- UPDATE 02 (BANK_NAME) --
    
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND OLD.BANK_NAME IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.BANK_NAME THEN

        SELECT 'MBANK' INTO EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
        SELECT 'BANK_NAME' INTO EVENT_COLUMN_NAME;
        
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_DATETIME INTO EVENT_DATETIME;                   --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER INTO EVENT_USER;                           --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT USER_NAME INTO EVENT_USER_NAME FROM MUSER WHERE USER_ID = EVENT_USER;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER_CC INTO EVENT_USER_CC;                     --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE INTO EVENT_MACHINE;                     --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP INTO EVENT_MACHINE_IP;               --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
         
        SELECT OLD.BANK_NAME INTO OLD_VALUE;                             --FROM OLD WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.BANK_NAME INTO NEW_VALUE;                             --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        
        SELECT OLD.BANK_CODE INTO BANK_CODE;                        --FROM OLD del WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT OLD.BANK_NAME INTO BANK_NAME;
        
        IF OLD_VALUE <> NEW_VALUE THEN
            EVENT_ACTIVITY := EVENT_USER || ' [' || EVENT_USER_NAME || '] has changed the name of the bank code ' || BANK_CODE || ' from "' || OLD_VALUE || '" to "' || NEW_VALUE || '"';
        END IF;
        
        IF EVENT_ACTIVITY <> '' THEN
            INSERT INTO MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP) 
            VALUES (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

 -- UPDATE 03 (WEB_ADDRESS) --
    
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND OLD.WEB_ADDRESS IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.WEB_ADDRESS THEN

        SELECT 'MBANK' INTO EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
        SELECT 'WEB_ADDRESS' INTO EVENT_COLUMN_NAME;
        
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_DATETIME INTO EVENT_DATETIME;                   --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER INTO EVENT_USER;                           --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT USER_NAME INTO EVENT_USER_NAME FROM MUSER WHERE USER_ID = EVENT_USER;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER_CC INTO EVENT_USER_CC;                     --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE INTO EVENT_MACHINE;                     --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP INTO EVENT_MACHINE_IP;               --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
         
        SELECT OLD.WEB_ADDRESS INTO OLD_VALUE;                             --FROM OLD WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.WEB_ADDRESS INTO NEW_VALUE;                             --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        
        SELECT OLD.BANK_CODE INTO BANK_CODE;                        --FROM OLD del WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT OLD.BANK_NAME INTO BANK_NAME;
        
        IF OLD_VALUE IS NULL THEN
            EVENT_ACTIVITY := EVENT_USER || ' [' || EVENT_USER_NAME || '] has added ' || NEW_VALUE || ' as the web address of the bank code "' || BANK_CODE || '"';
        ELSEIF OLD_VALUE <> NEW_VALUE THEN
            EVENT_ACTIVITY := EVENT_USER || ' [' || EVENT_USER_NAME || '] has changed the web address of the bank code ' || BANK_CODE || ' from "' || OLD_VALUE || '" to "' || NEW_VALUE || '"';
        END IF;
        
        IF EVENT_ACTIVITY <> '' THEN
            INSERT INTO MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP) 
            VALUES (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;`
    
-- UPDATE 04 (STATUS) --

    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND OLD.STATUS IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.STATUS THEN

        SELECT 'MBANK' INTO EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
        SELECT 'STATUS' INTO EVENT_COLUMN_NAME;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_DATETIME INTO EVENT_DATETIME;               --FROM INSERTED WHERE SNDR_NOTE = NEW.CLIENT_ID;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER INTO EVENT_USER;                       --FROM INSERTED WHERE SNDR_NOTE = NEW.CLIENT_ID;
        SELECT USER_NAME INTO EVENT_USER_NAME FROM MUSER WHERE USER_ID = EVENT_USER;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_USER_CC INTO EVENT_USER_CC;                 --FROM INSERTED WHERE CLIENT_ID = NEW.CLIENT_ID;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE INTO EVENT_MACHINE;                 --FROM INSERTED WHERE SNDR_NOTE = NEW.CLIENT_ID;
        SELECT NEW.MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP INTO EVENT_MACHINE_IP;           --FROM INSERTED WHERE SNDR_NOTE = NEW.CLIENT_ID;

        SELECT CASE WHEN OLD.STATUS = 1 THEN 'Active'
                    WHEN OLD.STATUS = 0 THEN 'In-Active' 
            END INTO OLD_VALUE;

        SELECT CASE WHEN NEW.STATUS = 1 THEN 'Active'
                    WHEN NEW.STATUS = 0 THEN 'In-Active' 
            END INTO NEW_VALUE;

        SELECT OLD.BANK_CODE INTO BANK_CODE;                            --FROM INSERTED WHERE SNDR_NOTE = NEW.SNDR_NOTE;
        SELECT OLD.BANK_CODE INTO BANK_CODE;                        --FROM INSERTED WHERE SNDR_NOTE = NEW.SNDR_NOTE;

        IF OLD_VALUE <> NEW_VALUE THEN
            EVENT_ACTIVITY := EVENT_USER || ' [' || EVENT_USER_NAME || '] has changed the status of the bank code ' || BANK_CODE || ' from "' || OLD_VALUE || '" to "' || NEW_VALUE || '"';
        END IF;

        IF EVENT_ACTIVITY <> '' THEN
            INSERT INTO MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP) 
            VALUES (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

-- DELETE DATA --
    
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
    
        SELECT 'MBANK' INTO EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
        SELECT 'BANK_CODE' INTO EVENT_COLUMN_NAME;
        
        SELECT OLD.MODIFIED_DATETIME INTO EVENT_DATETIME;          --FROM NEW WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT OLD.MODIFIED_USER INTO EVENT_USER;                  --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT USER_NAME INTO EVENT_USER_NAME FROM MUSER WHERE USER_ID = EVENT_USER;
        SELECT OLD.MODIFIED_USER_CC INTO EVENT_USER_CC;            --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT OLD.MODIFIED_MACHINE INTO EVENT_MACHINE;            --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT OLD.MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP INTO EVENT_MACHINE_IP;      --FROM NEW ins WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;

        SELECT OLD.BANK_CODE INTO OLD_VALUE;                    --FROM OLD del WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT NEW.BANK_CODE INTO NEW_VALUE;
        
        SELECT OLD.BANK_CODE INTO BANK_CODE;                        --FROM OLD del WHERE BANK_CODE = NEW.BANK_CODE;
        SELECT OLD.BANK_NAME INTO BANK_NAME;
               
        EVENT_ACTIVITY := EVENT_USER || ' [' || EVENT_USER_NAME || '] has deleted the "' || OLD_VALUE || '" bank code';
        
        IF EVENT_ACTIVITY <> '' THEN
            INSERT INTO MAUDACTIVITYEVENTS (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP) 
            VALUES (EVENT_TABLE_NAME, EVENT_COLUMN_NAME, EVENT_ACTIVITY, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_USER, EVENT_USER_CC, EVENT_MACHINE, EVENT_MACHINE_IP);
        END IF;
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
    
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.tr_mbankactaud()
    OWNER TO postgres;

-- table quarry

-- Table: public.mbank

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.mbank;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.mbank
(
    bank_code character varying(4) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    bank_abbreviation character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    bank_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    web_address character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status integer,
    created_datetime timestamp(6) without time zone,
    created_user character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_user_cc character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_machine character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_machine_ip character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    modified_datetime timestamp(6) without time zone,
    modified_user character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    modified_user_cc character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    modified_machine character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    modified_machine_ip character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT pk_mbank PRIMARY KEY (bank_code)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.mbank
    OWNER to postgres;

 
--Create trigger funtion

-- Trigger: tr_mbankactaud

-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_mbankactaud ON public.mbank;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_mbankactaud
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON public.mbank
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.tr_mbankactaud();




I wanted to make two audits if I change two things in same row but only first changed column make a record I need to fix it so it creates two records. I did the updates from pgAdmin 4. did the both updates and save them and execute them.
updates done in pgadmin4
UPDATE mbank
SET bank_abbreviation = 'HHH', status = 0
WHERE bank_code = '7010';

If you update a row twice, a row-level trigger will call the trigger function twice. So to answer the question, we'd need more information: 1) what is the CREATE TRIGGER statement 2) how exactly are the two updates performed?

What are the exact statements that "change two things"?

I have edited the question (what i done was changing BANK_ABBREVIATION first and  status(1 to 0) second and only BANK_ABBREVIATION record audits

I don't understand. Where is the statement that calls the trigger?

what do you mean by statement that calls the trigger?  the create trigger statement is in the bottom of the code and use pgadmin4 for updates every code i put is there. Is there something missing?

Triggers only get executed when you perform an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement on the table.

yes an I'm updating the table using pgadmin 4 edit table and updating two which has trigger functions and only first updated one makes the record I want the other one make a record too. i put a picture of pgadmin 4 Edit view

That doesn't help. We need the actual UPDATE statement.

UPDATE mbank
SET bank_abbreviation = 'HHH', status = 0
WHERE bank_code = '7010';
i did it using this and still it only make bank_abbreviation audit will this help? ill put tis on edit too

Sure, because you RETURN NEW; after logging the changed bank_abbreviation. That ends the execution of the trigger function, and you don't get the status change logged. Also, you should be careful with string concatenation: 'something' || NULL will result in NULL.

ok thanks, So if I put return null; after the delete function will the code be ok because if I putt return new; the delete function wont audit so what can I do to change this code

No, RETURN NULL; will also end execution of the function. You must not RETURN anything before you are done.

Thanks for your help I remove all RETURNS and add RETURN NULL before the end and it worked one again thanks for helping
